# Interpreting Stokes' theorem using the energy of a particle looping around a closed curve

Tags: energy, differential-geometry, vector-fields, conservative-field, intuition

We know that the work for a particle moving along a path $L=\partial S$ is $\int_{L} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s}$. Suppose the particle loops around this path once:
$$ \int_L \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s} = \int_{S} \left(\nabla \times \vec{F}\right) \cdot dA$$
It seems to me that if we have a particle moving in loops under the influence of a non-conservative force field, the curl of the force becomes a relevant physical quantity which contributes to the energy gained by the particle every time it loops.

But, could one, without knowledge of Stokes' theorem simply argue the quantity of right side *must* give the energy gained by the particle in a loop as well?

Comment: If the force is non-conservative then its highly unlikely that Stokes will apply.

Comment: How do you reason that? @MoziburUllah

Comment: My physics intuition plus that mathematically speaking the general Stokes law on manifolds holds when the force is conservative.

Comment: I am not sure about curved spaces but in flat space if it was true then it's pretty useless because the RHS would always evaluate to zero, giving no new information.

Comment: The general Stokes law, by the way, was originally found by abstracting the physical case.

Comment: The general Stokes law is true in both curved spaces and in any dimension. Using the language of differential forms and supposing the force is conservative, then the equations of EM is just a single equation. Moreover, this is true in any curved space. This is relevant to EM on curved spacetimes. Moreover, the analogous equations hold for Yang-Mills forces. Hence the general Stokes law is v. important in physics.

Comment: Yes, I understand and I have a vague understanding of differential forms. I am just saying I see no mathematical reason that stoke's should fail if force is non conservative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MoziburUllah's comment "If the force is non-conservative then its highly unlikely that Stokes will apply" is just wrong. As long as the vector field $\mathbf{F}$ (or more generally differential form $\omega$) is "nice enough" (eg $C^{\infty}$ would certainly work) and the domain of integration is "nice enough", Stokes theorem is always valid. So the applicability of Stokes theorem has to do with the smoothness of the objects involved (the field and the domain), and has NOTHING to do with whether the vector field is conservative (or more generally whether the differential form is exact).

To answer your question about whether it's possible to interpret $\int_S(\nabla \times \mathbf{F})\cdot d\mathbf{a}$ as the energy, without invoking Stokes, the answer is no, by a simple logical argument. By definition, the energy gained by a particle, when it is under the influence of a force field $\mathbf{F}$ and travels along along a loop $L$ is given by the line integral $\int_L\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{l}$. So, if I start with some funny expression, I must somehow relate it to a line integral. Then, and only then, can I say that the original expression (in your case $\int_S(\nabla \times \mathbf{F})\cdot d\mathbf{a}$) is related to the energy gained by a particle along a loop. Stokes theorem is precisely that connection!

In fact, I would say that it is Stokes theorem which allows us to physically give an interpretation of the curl of a vector field (i.e run the logic in the other direction). For example, fix a point $p\in \Bbb{R}^3$, and let $S_{r,p}$ be a surface containing the point $p$, and lying inside the $x,y$-plane, and such that it depends on some parameter $r>0$, whereby as $r\to 0^+$, the surface "shrinks nicely" to the point $p$ (for example, think of a disk centered at $p$). Then, (assuming $\vec{F}$ is $C^1$), by rearranging Stokes theorem, we see that the $z$-component of curl at point $p$ is
\begin{align}
[(\nabla \times \mathbf{F})(p)]_z&=\lim\limits_{r\to 0^+}\frac{1}{\text{area}(S_{r,p})}\int_{\partial S_{r,p}}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{l}
\end{align}
So, roughly speaking, this tells us that the $z$-component of curl is the "density of energy" gained by a particle as it traverses in loops perpendicular to the $z$-axis (I use the term "density" because we're dividing by the area, and I use "energy" because the line integral by definition is the energy gained). You can get similar interpretations for the $x$ and $y$ components of curl.

Answer (score 0):

In a word, yes.

Stokes' Theorem holds regardless of whether a field is conservative or not. The fact that a field is conservative merely means both the line integral and surface integral with both be zero. If they are not conservative, Stokes' theorem still holds - both sides of the equation remain equal, just not necessarily 0.

There are cases where the theorem doesn't hold, but as long as a region is simply connected, you can be sure of it.

[Here's a great article on the subject.](https://mathinsight.org/conservative_vector_field_determine)